# How to change ANTLR boolean precedence?

Tags: tree, boolean, antlr, operator-precedence

I have the following antler g file that works fine:

```
grammar BoolTest;

LEFT_PAREN : '(' ;
RIGHT_PAREN : ')' ;
AND : 'AND';
OR : 'OR';
WHITESPACE  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\r'
        | '\n'
        ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;    
WORD :  (~( ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' | '(' | ')' ))*;

expression : and_expression;
and_expression : or_expression (AND^ or_expression)*;
or_expression : atom (OR^ atom)*;
atom : WORD | LEFT_PAREN! expression RIGHT_PAREN!;
```

The problem is that I need AND to have a higher precedence than OR.  So I modified the last four lines as the following:

```
expression : or_expression;
or_expression : and_expression (OR^ and_expression)*;
and_expression : atom (AND^ atom)*;
atom : WORD | LEFT_PAREN! expression RIGHT_PAREN!;
```

But for some reason it doesn't work properly.  And the following expression:

```
a AND b OR c
```

produces the following tree, which is completely missing the OR branch:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the bug, it was actually a problem with the me using ANTLRWorks IDE.  When you run debug mode, and it asks you for text, one of the drop-downs states Start Rule:.  It was set to 'and_expression'.  After I changed it to just 'expression', the program works fine, and I get the following tree:

[image]

Comment: I fall for this as well, from time to time. Don't forget to accept your own answer!